# Choosing a precise frequency interval for power spectrum

Tags: python, numpy, fft, spectrum

I want to compare the power spectra of the time traces of two random processes but the frequency range returned is different.

How is that frequency range chosen and how can I modify it ?

More specifically, what I do is the following:

```
from scipy import signal as sgn

spectrum1=sgn.periodogram(signal1,fs=fs1)
spectrum2=sgn.periodogram(signal2,fs=fs2)
```

and my problem is that `spectrum1[0]` has a significantly different range with respect to `spectrum2[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `periodogram` is computed using FFT (Fast Fourier Transform), which implements the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform). The DFT of a periodic signal features discrete frequencies, all multiple of a fundamental frequency consistent with the duration of the frame `T` : `f_0=1/T`.

As a consequence, to get the same frequencies, the durations of the frame must be similar, of at least a multiple of one another:

```
len(signal1)/fs1 = k*len(signal2)/fs2
```

It may require to truncate one of the arrays. The argument `nfft` of [`scipy.signal.periodgram()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html) may also be tried, the requirement becomes:

```
nfft1/fs1 = k*nfft2/fs2
```

If the duration of the frame is not consistent with the actual period of the signal, or if the signal is not periodic, [windowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) may limit the effects of spectral leakage. It is so useful that it is integrated to [`scipy.signal.periodgram()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html) as an argument. You may try values `'hann'` or `'parzen'` as listed [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.get_window.html#scipy.signal.get_window).

If the sampling rates are not similar, resampling the signal may be required. To this end [scipy.signal.resample()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) can be applied. It also features the argument `window` and makes use of FFT for resampling, thus avoiding some errors that linear interpolation would trigger.